# Android logon persist

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android app. I made my login, all correct. But I have a problem the moment I hit the back button of my cell phone when I am in my main activity, that is to say the one on the side of the home, since it is as if I close the session.

How could I make the session persist and not be closed?

Currently I only have the login and logout with the following code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private final String clientId = "your-client-id";
    //private final String clientSecret = "password";
    //private final String redirectUri = "your://redirecturi";

    private final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
    private final String AUTHORIZATION = "Basic d2ViOnNlY3JldA==";

    TextInputEditText edt_user_account;
    TextInputEditText edt_password;
    CheckBox chk_rememberme;
    Button btn_login;
    private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

    AccessToken access_token;
    String user = null;
    String password = null;

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        chk_rememberme = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_rememberme);
        edt_user_account = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_user_account);
        edt_password = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesG11", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        user = prefs.getString("user_account", "");
        password = prefs.getString("password", "");
        //String user = "jvelasquez@applying.pe";
        //String password = "123456789";
        if(user!=null&&!user.isEmpty()&&password!=null&&!password.isEmpty()){
            login();
        }else {
            btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    user = edt_user_account.getText().toString();
                    password = edt_password.getText().toString();
                    if (password != null && !password.isEmpty() && user != null && !user.isEmpty()) {
                        login();
                    } else if (user == null || user.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.user_is_required), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if (password == null || password.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.password_is_required), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void login() {
        LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
        Call<AccessToken> call = loginService.getAccessToken("password", password, user, CONTENT_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
//                     if (response.isSuccess()) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    access_token = response.body();
                    System.out.println("LOGIN ACCESS TOKEN ->"+access_token.getAccess_token());

                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.remove("user_account");
                    editor.remove("password");
                    editor.remove("access_token");
                    editor.remove("user_bean");
                    editor.commit();

                    if(chk_rememberme.isChecked()) {
                        editor.putString("user_account", user);
                        editor.putString("password", password);
                    }

                    editor.putString("access_token", access_token.getAccess_token());

                    /*DATOS DEL USUARIO*/
                    LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
                    Call<UserAccountBean> callMe = loginService.getUserLogged(access_token.getAccess_token());

                    callMe.enqueue(new Callback<UserAccountBean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<UserAccountBean> call, Response<UserAccountBean> response) {
                            UserAccountBean userAccountBean = response.body();
                            editor.putString("user_fisrt_name",userAccountBean.getFirstName());
                            editor.putString("user_pattern_name",userAccountBean.getPatternName());
                            editor.putString("user_mail",userAccountBean.getUsername());
                            editor.putLong("user_id",userAccountBean.getId());

                            editor.commit();
                            editor.apply();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<UserAccountBean> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {
                // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.login_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This happens when I'm in the home of my application. I click on the back button on my cell phone and it redirects me to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SessionManager` class to save a user session, `SessionManager` needs to be a singleton so only one instance is created.

Sample example:

```
public class SessionManager { 

    private static SessionManager mInstance;

    private SessionManager(){

    }

    public static synchronized SessionManager getInstance(){
       if(mInstance == null){
          mInstance = new SessionManager();
       }

       return mInstance
   }
}
```

---

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. Can you tell me when to use this class? I would appreciate it if you could explain. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions could be to implement some kind of `BaseActivity`. All your activities should extend this one. So inside this `BaseActivity`'s `onCreate` you should have something like following :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if (!checkSession()) {
         launchLoginScreen(); 
         finish()
     }         
}
```

The `checkSession` method verifies `SharedPreferences` that session is valid and not expired. Such approach make sure that when user goes back to your app after a while through recent apps list you have a chance to correctly handle session expiration and show user the login screen.

Another approach could be to create some kind of `LaunchingActivity`. This activity should be places as a main entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` so all intents should go through it. Inside this activity you could place something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if (!checkSession()) {
         launchLoginScreen();
     } else {
         launchMainScreen();
     } 

     finish()
}
```

So If you are worried only about start up login this could be what are you looking for. But with this approach you should carefully analyze your navigation flows.

Answer (score 0):

Save your authenticate token in preferences, and when you do request, load token from preferences.

Refresh your token when user do login.